# Let iOS Facebook SDK share photo from my native app

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I I need to install my app on an ipad in an exhibition stand. The application flow is:

1) User takes a photo

2) User taps on a facebook button. That open the Facebook Web View Login. The user makes the login and automatically returns to my app. Then the Facebook share dialog appears and the user shares its photo.

I have this code.

```
    let fbSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbSDKLoginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(["publish_actions"]
    fromViewController: self) { (result, error) in
        if (error != nil){
            return;
        }
        if result.isCancelled{
            return;
        }

        let photo = FBSDKSharePhoto()
        photo.image = self.photoImage
        photo.userGenerated = true
        let content = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
        content.photos = [photo]


        FBSDKShareDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: content, delegate: self)
    }
```

I don't know why if i don't have the Facebook app installed, the result in the first block return "is cancelled".

If I have the Facebook app installed, I only can share if my the account which is saved in the Facebook app is the same as the one that I use to share when a make the login in the web view of my native app.

If I don't have an account in the Facebook app, the result in the first block return "is cancelled".

Please help me with this. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Thank you very much!